# Calling and passing variables values between shell scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Bash
```

I am trying to get one shell script to pass variables to another script and execute it. Here's what I tried:

**mainscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Master script
SUBSCRIPT1_PATH=~/subscript1.sh
test_string="The cat ate the canary"
(exec "$SUBSCRIPT1_PATH")
```

**subscript1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# subscript1.sh
echo $test_string
```

But, when I do:

```
bash mainscript.sh
```

I get nothing. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `(exec "$SUBSCRIPT1_PATH")` is equivalent to `"$SUBSCRIPT1_PATH"`

Comment: The parentheses are not needed around your `exec` statement, by the way.

Comment: Use `source` command or `export`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables are by default not visible in child processes. To pass them to children use the `export` keyword:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Master script
SUBSCRIPT1_PATH=~/subscript1.sh
export test_string="The cat ate the canary"
(exec "$SUBSCRIPT1_PATH")
```